# HTTPS in S3 (only the HTTPS is working in the cloudfront domain, but not on the one defined)

Tags: amazon-s3

i imported my certificate to the "Certificate Manager" and it indicates my domain and everything in the "details section".

After having done everything in the cloudfront part, it gives me the cloudfront domain which it loads with HTTPS, but the main domain does not.

Why is that?

cloudfront domain: d6y63izpha76j.cloudfront.net

on the cnames i added my domain: which is hackerload.com .

but there are no results at all.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Update your DNS to point to CloudFront.  It's still pointing at S3.

Comment: How can i do that? Sorry, i'm new to AWS.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-cloudfront-distribution.html